# I got an error when trying to execute "mysql -u root -p" ER_PARSE_ERROR on PopSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I'm still learning SQL and I get an error when trying to execute "MySQL 8.0 Command Line" using `mysql -u root -p` on PopSQL.
I got the following error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mysql -u root -p' at line 1.
Error Code: ER_PARSE_ERROR
```

I don't know why is this happening.

I tried closing and restarting PopSQL and the PC but non of them worked...

Answer (score 0):

This is when you are connected to the database and have a session, it will only accept queries or support options like \h ...

> mysql - u root -p

is used to connect to MySQL server on Terminal or CommandLine , Once you are connected you have to use SQL commands like Create table , ....

Comment: I am following the freeCodeCamp SQL Tutorial, I created a server on my computer using MySQL 8.0 Command Line but I can't access to it when executing "MySQL -u root -p".

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. Sorry for late replying... I was out for a week